# PayPal payment integration difficulties

Tags: cognito-forms

I already have a PayPal business account but when I click on "Add Payment Account +" and then the "Login with PayPal" button it takes me straight to a sign up page and I can't login to my PayPal account to link it to  my form. I need to launch my form today.

Can someone please help me with linking my PayPal to my [form](https://www.cognitoforms.com/WTIA1/ConferenceAwardsDinnerEventRegistration)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). Unfortunately, post release, we were informed that PayPal's integrated sign up does not support PayPal accounts based out of the following countries, Australia, India, Brazil, Japan, Israel, and Canada.

We currently have an update going through testing that will allow you to enter your existing PayPal business email address to link your PayPal account to your form/organization.

We're hoping the update will be released within the next couple of weeks.